# Preventing wasted effort when user has a history of letting their bounties expire

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I just got auto-awarded by the system, 50% of the original bounty on this question

[Inheritance and responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134950/inheritance-and-responsibility)

because the person offering the bounty let it expire.

While I'm certainly pleased to get the little blue fifty rep badge, I must admit that it's disappointing that it's not 100, as it was supposed to be.

The user, as of the time I'm writing this, has still given no feedback on any of the answers.

I also checked their other offered bounty

[Reusable form choices in symfony2 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090910/reusable-form-choices-in-symfony2-forms)

and noticed that no one received the bounty in that question either (although I don't understand why it's *none*--I expected someone to have been auto-awarded half). Perhaps the user felt no answer was worthy in this case, which is a possible reasonable response.

Although it may not have helped in this particular case (as they only had a history of one bounty), it would be nice to have a summary of the user's bounty-giving history somewhere in the bounty announcement. While I can browse their bounty question list, one-by-one, in their user profile, something like this would be informative:

"Bounty offered, 100 points, expires in 3 days. User has offered 1 bounty in in the past, and has awarded 0."

Or

"...User has offered 1 bounty in in the past for a total of 50 points, and has awarded 0 points."

If I saw this, I would have thought twice about investing the time and effort that I did. For users with a solid history with bounties--positive or negative--this information could be enlightening.

Thank you for considering.

Comment: It's discouraging to be offered a potential bounty that never comes to pass, when the level of effort you put into answering a bountied question is obviously going to be more than a non-bountied question. Without some solution such as this, it forces the potential answerer to have to do research on the user's past bounty questions, *one-by-one*, to make sure you're not going to get screwed over. So now it's even *more* effort to answer a bountied question. :(

Comment: Perhaps there could be a summary in the user's profile that gives essentially the same information as I've suggested in my question-post, but now it's up to the potential-answerer to go out and find it, instead of it being more obviously and publicly displayed in the bounty annoucement. It would be nice, at the least, to not have to do this one-question-at-a-time research. At some level, there should either be some privately-done consequence, if the user keeps expiring their bounties on an ongoing basis. Either that, or make it a little easier for potential answers to figure it out themselves.

Comment: Even if you did that you're still potentially taking the focus away from the question and putting it onto the user - which is where it doesn't belong. You should be answering based on the merits of the question alone, not "whether or not it has a bounty" or "is the OP likely to upvote/accept/reward me for answering". The reputation is a nice-to-have, it should not be the end goal of your activities on SO.

Comment: But if it *really* bothers you that much, I'm sure you can write a SEDE query that just takes a user ID and run that for each bountied question you're contemplating answering. I just don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: "You should be answering based on the merits of the question alone, not 'whether or not it has a bounty' or 'is the OP likely to upvote" it. Then what's the point of bounties and up-voting? We're all on stackoverflow for the love of programming, but reputation points are the artificial little thingies that (a) make it fun, like accumulating points in a video game, and

Comment: (b) are used as serious currency on SO when it comes to [getting new privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), in [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) where, because of my reputation within certain categories, I have a cool little "Top 10% for java, regex" at the top, and when using your profile to brag about yourself to potential employers. A blue `[100]` badge under "received bounties" and next to the answer itself, is significantly more impressive than the two-digit, not-a-multiple-of-10 `[50]`. (Yes, I'm looking for a job :)

Comment: Is it though? I can't imagine any potential employer lending any real weight to the amount of reputation you've received on StackOverflow from bounties. It doesn't really say anything about your abilities as a programmer - it's not unheard of that crap questions get bountied, which makes it unreliable as a metric. As a minor aside, 50 *is* a multiple of 10...suspect that's probably a typo and you meant 100?

Comment: "disappointing that it's not 100, as it was supposed to be" is your mistake. It's only "supposed to be" if the user awards you that bounty, and the user didn't award it to you, so your expectations were wrong if you felt it should be otherwise. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps? Please link to the location on this site that said "Posting any answer to a question that has a bounty will guarantee that you will receive 100% of that bounty regardless of any other conditions". Can't find one? Right. In order to receive the entire bounty, the answer must be awarded that bounty specifically, and this is explained (as is the information about receiving only part of that bounty if it isn't awarded to a specific answer). There's no "perhaps" here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm admitting that there's a selfish element to my asking this question. That's all I'm trying to do here. Lighten up.

Answer (score 19):

I disagree with this for a number of reasons.

1. **It takes the focus away from the question**
2. **It's not an accurate metric**
3. **It encourages users to award bounties to bad answers to maintain their "award rate"**
4. **It's a vicious cycle**

### It takes the focus away from the question

StackOverflow is (and hopefully always will be) a *Question and Answer* site, dedicated to compiling and maintaining a collection of high quality questions and their answers. *Who* provides those questions and answers is irrelevant - as long as they're high quality.

By displaying a "bounty award rate" on either the question or on the user's profile we do nothing to further that goal. It says "you don't deserve our time because you haven't awarded enough of your bounties, so we're going to ignore your questions until you fix it" (see point 4). That is to say, it focuses the attention of the would-be answerers onto the asker instead of the question.

### It's not an accurate metric

A "bounty award rate" would be a flawed metric (but that wouldn't stop the above mentality from developing). It's just a statistic with no contextual information behind it. What if the reason that someone didn't award a bounty to an answer was because they didn't feel it answered their question to their satisfaction? Perhaps no answers were even posted during the bounty period (Such as happened with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986661/issue-with-recording-from-open-network-video-interface-forum-onvif-device))? There are *plenty* of reasons why a bounty might not be manually awarded. Users shouldn't be penalised for not manually awarding bounties when it's not appropriate to do so, which leads me on to...

### It encourages users to award bounties to bad answers

Say this "bounty award rate" became a reality and I post a bounty on one of my questions. After the bounty period is up, there's only one answer on my question, and it's a bad answer. What do I do? I don't want to award the bounty to a bad answer, because that sends the wrong signals to the community. It says I found that answer useful when I didn't, and potentially opens up a whole other can of worms when the recipient starts badgering for an accept mark, just because it was "good enough to get the bounty".

But equally, I don't want to get punished for *not* awarding it, because if I don't then people may pass over my bountied questions in the future as a result. *Some* people given this situation will award a bounty to a crap answer just to maintain their award rate, which would be a Bad Thing.

### It's a vicious cycle

If you ever got caught out by this it would be *very difficult* to get out of it. You can't post a bounty on one of your questions to up your accept rate, because everyone's ignoring your question, so it gets no answers. So you have nobody to award the bounty to - making your award rate *even worse*.

The only way out of that would be to offer bounties on questions that *already have* satisfactory/good answers and then award them as soon as you could to get your award rate up. And let's face it, a fair number of people would rather just create a new account and start with a clean award rate than try and fix a bad one.

### Related Reading

[Showing the accept rate discourages asking hard questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/showing-the-accept-rate-discourages-asking-hard-questions?rq=1)

[Are people less tolerant of questions from users with a low accept rate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21590/are-people-less-tolerant-of-questions-from-users-with-a-low-accept-rate?rq=1)

[Is it appropriate to comment on people's accept rate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate?rq=1)

[Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate?lq=1) (Probably the most important one)

Comment: There are a number of other reasons that I don't agree with this, but these were the four that I felt were the most important.

Comment: I agree with the "It encourages users to award bounties to bad answers" point. I'll read the related links. I don't see the big picture yet.

Comment: I especially agree with "It's not an accurate metric" -- as a user who has only ever offered one bounty - and let it expire due to no answers that helped solve my problem - this would send the wrong signal.

Answer (score 5):

You don't know whether they liked your answer or felt it really solved their problem well enough to reward you with the bounty.  The bounty isn't a guarantee that they will get an answer, nor a guarantee that an answerer will receive the bounty.

It's quite possible that they felt they couldn't award the bounty, and in this case the system awards half of it to you, because others felt it was a good addition to the problem and voted it up.

This despite the OP's specific feelings about the answer.

You got 90 reputation for providing that answer, between upvotes and the auto-bounty.  It's only a little short of the 100 you were trying for.

It seems to me that the system is operating well, and has actually served you well.  Had you seen a bounty history that made you avoid it, you would have missed out on 90 reputation.

If, however, this is still not satisfying, then when you are bounty hunting, visit the user's page and click on `bounties`.  Check out their bounty history and decide for yourself.  At the moment your argument for an easy or obvious metric is too weak to act on, but if you gather evidence of bounty abuse (and again, there's little evidence here that the OP in question is actually abusing bounties) then present it and ask for a fix.

Comment: In the meantime, place the 90 rep you gained on the floor, roll around in it, close your eyes, and pretend it's the 115 rep you were expecting. Alternately, wait around patiently for [me to post another bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis?tab=bounties&sort=offered)

Comment: +1, with a comment: I agree with everything you said except for the note about the OP abusing bounties; I see no potential way to "abuse bounties", because the poster offered 100 rep as a bounty and it cost them 100 in rep. The only issue I see with the post here is that the poster of the question here had invalid expectations ("If I post an answer, I'll receive a full bounty of 100 points, and if I don't get it I'll feel deprived."). If a poster feels the need to "bounty hunt", IMO they're at SO for the wrong reasons.