# What to do when a user abandons a bounty question and refuses to provide clarifying details?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I'm looking [specifically at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819596/passing-urls-to-relational-collections-in-backbone), where a user offered a bounty, participated a good bit in a discussion of the problem in the comments, but now will no longer respond to questions about his problem, and so it seems unlikely that an "answer" will ever be found. This kind of behavior has occurred in other posts I've participated in as well. Now it looks like the bounty will expire without being awarded to anyone, and there is no clear, useful answer to the question. What's the correct response from a moderation or voting standpoint? I downvoted the question (as it has become obvious that it can not be answered well, though there are still 5 upvotes) but is there anything else I can do?

I like the idea of establishing a ["bounty history"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262758/preventing-wasted-effort-when-user-has-a-history-of-letting-their-bounties-expir) to identify serial bounty abandoners, but agree with some of the responses that not selecting a bounty is not always the result of bad etiquette on the part of the question asker, but instead a result of not getting any good answers. Maybe we should have a feature where, rather than tracking bounties, we could downvote a bounty asker's 'bounty reputation' allowing potential answerers to see when others have had a bad experience with a bounty offerer, or even to allow moderators to prevent a bad bounty user from offering bounties in the future.

Comment: This particular user also has a [history of abandoning bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485093/any-way-of-detecting-whether-a-browsers-console-is-able-to-render-colors).

Comment: What makes you think your answer deserves the bounty points? Also the OP can award bounty points only at a specific timeframe before the bounty gets closed IIRC.

Comment: I'm not arguing that I deserve the bounty. I'm arguing that the user was wrong to abandon the question, or at least not post a solution to his own question, if he found it.

Comment: Read the last few paragraphs in [What is a bounty?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), if your answer get's minimum 2 upvotes, you'll get half the bounty automatically

Comment: @Morslamina What do you mean _abandon_? Not accepting an answer? That's nothing to do with the bounty points.

Comment: @ArunA.S I've read the discussion of bounties. I guess I'm wondering if people feel it's appropriate behavior to ask a question with a bounty, have an extended discussion about the details of that question, and then refuse to follow up with code or respond to further questions about the issue. That seems like behavior SO should discourage, but maybe others disagree.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean, I've added comments to the question specifically asking for additional details to help him with his problem, and he has not responded.

Comment: Well just stop wasting your time with that question. If the OP doesn't want to clarify, that's their issue. If they don't want to award, that's their choice too. Bounties are advertising. Answering bountied questions doesn't entitle you to the bounty rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A user is free to distribute their rep in bounties as they please, so long as they understand the consequences of doing so. The system has procedures for automatically awarding partial bounties to answers with enough votes so that the effort put in by answerers doesn't go entirely to waste, but if you know that a user has a history of asking poor questions, ignoring comments and abandoning their bounties, then you are not obligated to engage them or their questions. The bounty reputation will vanish permanently if there are no adequate answers by the time the bounty expires. If the user offering the bounty doesn't care about wasting their rep and losing privileges, that's their prerogative. Otherwise, they can't complain about the system working as intended.

If the questions really are that unclear, you may vote to close them once the bounty period is over.